# facebook feed on personal page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I Use the Facebook API Graph on my website to feed posts.
The problem is that I can't figure out how to feed on my facebook **personal** page. I can only feed on my facebook normal page.

The feed looks like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=xxxxxxxxxx
&redirect_uri=https://www.mywebsite.com
&link=https://www.mywebsite.com/
&title=title
&picture=https://www.mywebsite.com/picture.png
&caption=caption&description=description
```

Can I add somewhere the url of my persosnal page to post directly on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Feed Dialog, you can only post to your user profile. Try the Share Dialog instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

...you can even omit all parameters except for the URL, because it will just get the data from the Open Graph Tags.

If that does not work, you can also use `sharer.php`: `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[urlencoded-url]`